# Can we to send & get "requestCode" with "registerForActivityResult"?

Tags: android

Because `startActivityForResult` is deprecated.
So I replace `startActivityForResult` to `registerForActivityResult`

This is my code:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        //Intent data = result.getData();
                        //doSomeOperations();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Because i call to multi Activity:

Old Version:

```
 Intent myinten = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
 startActivityForResult(myinten, 111);

Intent myinten = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity3.class);
startActivityForResult(myinten, 222);
```

New Version:

```
Intent myinten = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
someActivityResultLauncher.launch(myinten);

Intent myinten = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity3.class);
someActivityResultLauncher.launch(myinten);
```

Can we to send & get "requestCode" with "registerForActivityResult"?

Comment: You don't need or use request codes when using the Activity Result APIs. What are you actually trying to do with request codes?

Comment: I must to discern result of MainActivity2 or MainActivity3.

Comment: If you want two different callbacks, why are you using a single launcher instead of two of them, each with their own callback?

Comment: oh, If I call earch Actitivity , i have to create a ActivityResultLauncher. It will very waste.

Comment: What makes you think it is any "waste" at all? You said you wanted different callbacks.

Comment: @ianhanniballake This is a valid use case. `registerForActivityResult` suppose able to port from `startActivityForResult` with little effort. `startActivityForResult` is able to accept requestCode. Hence, it makes sense for app developer to expect `registerForActivityResult` able to do so too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Either create a new ActivityResultLauncher for each launch or pass your own identifier in a bundle when launching the activity.

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent intent = result.getData();
                        //get your "requestCode" here with switch for "SomeUniqueID"
                    }
                }
            });
```

Launch Activity

```
Intent myinten = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
myinten.putExtra("requestCode", "SomeUniqueID");
someActivityResultLauncher.launch(myinten);
```

Activity which returns

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
//these should not be hard coded, but retrieved from the intent which created this activity
intent.putExtra("requestCode", "SomeUniqueID");
activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
activity.finish();
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work when it created and intent to launch system activity like gallery system aplication. The Intent is override an any extra value it will return null object Intent intent = result.getData(); some solutions to this case please?

Comment: It depends on the System Activity which is being launched.  Some System activities (i.e. Permissions) have a request code.  Others (i.e.  BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE) do not.  So if there is no request code then use a new instance of ActivityResultLauncher or use Semaphores or Threads to ensure the result is returned before any other activities are launched from the same ActivityResultLauncher.

Comment: So have to create separate result launcher for all the intent right?  @JavierRefuerzo

Comment: @GvHarish that is likely the easiest method for a system Activity when the intent does not accept a request ID.  However you may want to expose the result to other classes with observation, in which case threading can be used to ensure only one request is made and returned.